# How to silently get a new access token using refresh token in Google Oauth NodeJS Library

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-oauth

I am using the Google OAuth NodeJS Library to do oauth stuffs.

I have gotten the access token from an authenticated user.

While using the access token I noticed that after a while, I keep getting this error that `Refresh Token is not set`. I know, the ideal thing to do is to regenerate a new auth url and force the User to reauthenticate against the app. I do not want to stress my users that way.

So, how can I silently get a new access token via the refresh token.

Here is what I have tried.

```
    const oauth2Client = initOAuth2Client();
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(authCredentials);
    oauth2Client.on('tokens', async (tokens) => {
        if (tokens.refresh_token) {
              //I do not want to wait for this callback. I want to force refresh the access token silently whenever I get the error that Refresh Token is not set.
        }
    });
```

I wanted something like

```
const newToken = oauth2Client.forceRefreshAccessToken(refreshToken);//unfortunately, no such thing seems available in the library
```

Is there a work around?

Comment: Your code should set the refresh token when the user authorizes your application for the first time.   which api are you trying to access?

Comment: @DaImTo I know that. The token expires after some time. I don't want that. The question is how to refresh the token when it expires.